# Gather_table_stats always updates stats

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

In ODI we used the DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS to recompute the stats only when a table changed by a certain percentage with the option (options => 'GATHER AUTO'). (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i1036456)

Now I want to move the calculation of statistics to the table level (in the IKL) but DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS does not seem to have a setting to only recompute the stats if they need an update (determined by Oracle). 
(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i1036461)

Always recomputing the statistics of all our tables is too costly.

Does anyone know a way to check if a table needs its statistics updated or a hidden option in DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i1036456) has an option to LIST STALE objects; you could run that first and decide if your table is in the list of returned objects.

Answer (score 2):

Check the column STALE_STATS from USER_TAB_STATISTICS / ALL_TAB_STATISTICS / DBA_TAB_STATISTICS